# ClipCursor doesn't work with Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I wrote an application which uses `ClipCursor` to confine the mouse within an area of my window. I tested and it works well on a Win7 machine.

However, when I use Remote Desktop Connection on my Mac to connect that Win7 machine, `ClipCursor` doesn't work: it will move the cursor to the designated area (if it wasn't in that area previously). But the cursor is not confined to that area, I can move out of it freely.

Do you know how to get `ClipCursor` also work with Remote Desktop?